# Why do I get an exception when trying to run .class file made with Jython? How can I solve it?

Tags: java, python, class, jython

I just found out about Jython and I really wanted to use it. Please forgive me if I'm doing something wrong and please explain.
I made a simple python program to test Jython, test.py. When typing

```
jython test.py
```

in the command prompt it run normally. So I decided to make a Java .class file. Since jythonc doesn't exist anymore, I tried

```
jython -m py_compile test.py
```

and a .class file was created in the same directory called test$py.class.
(this is equivalent to

```
>>> import py_compile
>>> py_compile.compile('test.py')
```

as I tried as well)

However, when I tried

```
java test$py
```

it threw me an exception:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class test$py
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/python/core/PyRunnable
```

(I also tried with classpath but it did the same exception)

What does it mean? How can I solve it?

Note: I've downloaded Jython 2.5.4rc1.

Comment: 2.5.4rc1 is quite old. The latest release is 2.7.1: https://jython.github.io/download

Comment: I'll try it, thanks.
I downloaded the above version because I thought 2.7.0 was the latest. It didn't work on my computer so I chose an older version.

Comment: I just downloaded it and tried it. It still doesn't work...
I also noticed the directory path C:\jython2.7.1\tests\java\org\python\core and there is nothing called PyRunnable. So I guess that's the issue?

Comment: I think you need jython.jar in the classpath. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15446116/407651

Comment: @mzjn Thanks, it works that way.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a corrupted installation of jython as per simillar [Linux: NoClassDefFoundError org/python/core/PyException #1006](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/issues/1006) issue. If you can find `jython-standalone-2.5.3.jar` and it's not corrupted you may want to try re-downloading and re-installing jython.